# {"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I tried to click on the Kibana-Link from the ES-cluster.
But, I receive this error:

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}
```

The access policy of the ES cluster is:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/my-role"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpGet",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:account-number:domain/my-es-domain/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:account-number:domain/my-es-domain/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "SourceIp": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the code:

```
const policy1: PolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: ["arn:aws:es:my-region:account-number:domain/my-es-domain/*"],
      actions: ["es:ESHttpGet"],
      principals: [
        new ArnPrincipal("arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/my-role")
      ],
    });

    const policy2: PolicyStatement = new PolicyStatement({
      effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      resources: ["arn:aws:es:my-region:account-number:domain/my-es-domain/*"],
      actions: ["es:*"],
      principals: [
        new ArnPrincipal("*")
      ],
      conditions: {
        IpAddress: {
          SourceIp: ["xx.xxx.xxx.xx"]
        }
      }
    });

    // es cluster 
    // @ts-ignore
    const elasticsearchDomain = new Domain(this,
      'ElasticsearchDomain',
      {
        accessPolicies: [policy1, policy2],
        domainName: 'my-es-domain',
        version: ElasticsearchVersion.V7_10,
        capacity: {
          dataNodeInstanceType: "r6g.large.elasticsearch"
        }
      }
    );
```

When my application is deployed, I can not click on the Kibana-Link in the ES-Cluster, but if I modify the access policy above to:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/my-role"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpGet",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:account-number:domain/my-es-domain/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:my-region:account-number:domain/my-es-domain/*",
      "Condition": {
        "IpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": "xx.xxx.xxx.xx"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then it works.

The only difference of the access policy is this statement in the principal:

```
"Principal": {
     "AWS": "*"
  }
```

Does anybody know, how to fix it?
Or how I should programmatically adjust my code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error would indicate your ElasticSearch service does not support anonymous requests (those not signed with valid IAM credentials).